# Перенос новостей на новую страницу

Tags: php, html, css

Пишу тему wordpress  с нуля и столкнулся с проблемой, на странице записей получается слишком много записей и хотелось бы сделать как на нормальных сайтах разные страницы с новостями, на первой странице 10 новостей чтобы 11 переходила новую страницу и между ними можно было бы переключатся.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно выполнить ряд действий

1. в functions.php добавить код пагинации вы можете добавить ее и отредактировать под свои нужды

   ```
    <?php
   ```

   function pagination() { // функция вывода пагинации
   global $wp_query; // текущая выборка должна быть глобальной
   $big = 5; // число для замены
   echo paginate_links(array( // вывод пагинации с опциями ниже
   'base' => str_replace($big,'%#%',esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))), // что заменяем в формате ниже
   'format' => '?paged=%#%', // формат, %#% будет заменено
   'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')), // текущая страница, 1, если $_GET['page'] не определено
   'type' => 'list', // ссылки в ul
   'prev_text'    => '', // текст назад
   'next_text'    => '', // текст вперед
   'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages, // общие кол-во страниц в пагинации
   'show_all'     => false, // не показывать ссылки на все страницы, иначе end_size и mid_size будут проигнорированны
   'end_size'     => 1, //  сколько страниц показать в начале и конце списка (12 ... 4 ... 89)
   'mid_size'     => 3, // сколько страниц показать вокруг текущей страницы (... 123 5 678 ...).
   'add_args'     => false, // массив GET параметров для добавления в ссылку страницы
   'add_fragment' => '',   // строка для добавления в конец ссылки на страницу
   'before_page_number' => '', // строка перед цифрой
   'after_page_number' => '' // строка после цифры
   ));
   }
2. Проверить параметры вызова функции потов. К примеру если вы достаете посты с помощью функции get_posts($args); Где

   $showposts = get_option('posts_per_page');
   $args = array(
   'cat' => 1,
   'posts_per_page' => $showposts,
   'paged'           => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
   'orderby'                => 'date',
   'order'                  => 'ASC'
   );
   ?>

Опять же отредактируйте под себя.
3) В шаблоне категории или страницы вызовите функцию, `<?php pagination(); ?>`

Ну и все, далее вы сможете изменять количество записей в админ панели (Настройки -> чтение).